# For Loop through a List with very similar names without rewriting code

Tags: c#, list

I have a List of strings where each of these strings is the final text of a list.

For example,

```
List<string> textEnds = New List<string>()
textEnds.Add("Q1"); textEnds.Add("Q2");
```

And I have these Lists already declared:

```
List<List<string>> someTextQ1 = new List<List<string>>();
List<List<string>> someTextQ2 = new List<List<string>>();
```

For each of the double lists above, I display a simple html table. Ideally I don't want to keep copy pasting the html code 100 times just because Q1 changes to Q2 in the double list names. Is there a way to write a for loop so that I do something like (obviously the below doesn't work, just a concept):

```
for(int i = 0; i < textEnds.Count; i++){
     <table>
          for(int j = 0; j < someText + textEnds[i] + .Count; j++){
          }
     </table>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To abstract `someTextQ1` and `someTextQ2`, etc., you simply need another list.

```
var someTexts = new List<List<List<string>>>();
```

This is beginning to look... recursive, so you might want to consider a recursive data structure:

```
class SomeText
{
    string Text { get; set; }
    List<string> SubTexts { get; set; }
}
```

The recursive structure has the benefit of being able to nest as deeply as you want.